# R determine image width and height in pixels

Tags: r, image, height, width

Suppose I have an image on disk, `image.jpg`. How can I determine image width in pixels using R?

Comment: brute-force could be to read the image e.g. with the jpeg package. I believe EBImage has various tools, so does RimageJ.

Comment: Thanks. I found the readbitmap package also, which does jpg, png and bmp

Comment: If you are on a *NIX system you can get this information from the file header without loading the file into into memory. You can also use `exif` or imagemagick for something a little more bombproof. Example:
`as.numeric(system(sprintf("file %s | cut -d ',' -f 11 | cut -d 'x' -f 1", <my_file_name>), intern = TRUE))`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `jpeg` package.
Code should be pretty self-explanatory:

```
require(jpeg)
img <- readJPEG("myimage.jpg") 

dim(img)
[1] 700 700   3
```

The same author (Simon Urbanek) also provided the `png` and `tiff` package, that have functions with similar syntax (`readPNG` and `readTIFF`)

Comment: Thanks. I found the readbitmap package also, which does jpg, png and bmp.