# How to get image width and height in pixels without loading file in memory

Tags: r, image, file, image-processing

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978549/r-determine-image-width-and-height-in-pixels), but I have thousands of images on disk and I want to fast read their width and height in pixels without loading each file in memory.

On my Linux machine, I could do something like this for each file:

```
path_to_file <- 'img/13600061.jpg'
system(sprintf("file %s", path_to_file), intern = TRUE)
```

But the output of `file` can differ for jpg, jpeg and png files and then I need to catch the pixel info differently depending on the file. I was wondering if there is a general fast solution out there already.

Comment: Do you know anything more about the images? Are they all JPEG or PNG or TIF? DO you have multiple CPU cores available? What OS are you running? Do you have an NVME SSD?

Comment: the metadata should exist and be readable in O(1), if you use the right library. the worst possible solution, that *will work*, would be to run a "Image Magick" subprocess, catch stdout and parse it. and that's not so bad.

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell, thanks for the questions. I use an Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, but I might need to run this on a Windows 10 machine as well. I do have multiple CPUs available, but hopefully, the task should not get that heavy. There are thousands of these images, stored in folders of around 2000 img each. Their extensions can be .jpg, .JPG, .jpeg, .png (I guess the .JPG is treated the same as .jpg?) I have a SSD, but a lot of these images are also stored remotely on a netwrok drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `exiftool` fits the bill nicely here. It runs on all platforms, is very controllable and crucially, it can recurse on its own so it doesn't incur the overhead of being started once per file.

As a rough first attempt, you'd want something like this if processing PNGs and JPEGs and recursing down starting at current directory, i.e. `.`

```
exiftool -csv -ImageHeight -ImageWidth -r -ext jpg -ext jpeg -ext png .
```

**Sample Output**

```
black.png,80,80
blue.png,80,80
c.jpg,1,1
deskew/skew40.png,800,800
deskew/gradient.png,800,800
```

You may want to add `-q` to exclude the summary if you are parsing the output.

As a rough guide, the above command runs in 9 seconds on a directory containing 10,000 images on my Mac.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this tool. I would like to get the output back to R, and I am not that familiar with all the output arguments of exiftool. Something like this `test <- system(paste("exiftool -q -csv -ImageHeight -ImageWidth", dir_path_img), intern = TRUE)` returns a character vector with the first element containing the header. I think I can work with that, but if you have a better suggestion, feel free to add it.

Comment: Glad it is looking hopeful for you. I don't know R, so we are separated by a bit of an ocean! I presume R can parse a CSV though, so maybe you could do `system("exiftool -ImageHeight ... > FileThatRcanParse.csv"` which would require you to enable the `shell` option if there is one on `system()` in R.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I can do something like `system2(command = "exiftool", args = c("-q", "-csv", "-ImageHeight", "-ImageWidth", dir_path_img), stdout = "test.csv")` and then read directly that csv file. I put this option here as a comment in case is useful for some other R user.  `dir_path_img` is a character vector of length 1 with the path to the directory containing the images, something like `dir_path_img <- "data/img-types"`.